# MD5 Checker Error: Too many variables (expected 4), Possible other issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to programming and have just started work experience. I have been asked to produce two applications. One which gets and stores file information such as the file's name, size, last modified time, and MD5 Checksum, and then write a file containing that data for multiple files; this program works fine.

My second program, which I will post code for below, is supposed to check the file created and compare it against the current conditions of the file. If the MD5 sum changes along with other properties, then the program would not give a warning. However, if all properties remain the same but the MD5 changes, then the program would put out a warning, as something went wrong.

The issue I am having is getting the checker program to work. I am a beginner so I would appreciate it if someone would perhaps take a look at my code and see where I've slipped up.

here is the code which I have produced.

```
 files = glob('C:\pytesty\*\*')


filecheck = open('MD5report.dat', 'r')
for fil3 in files:
          fil3md5 = open(fil3, 'rb')
          md5read = fil3md5.read()
          hashy = hashlib.md5(md5read).hexdigest()
          filsize = os.path.getsize(fil3)
          filtime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(fil3))
          fline = filecheck.readline()
          [finame, fiMD5, fiSize, fidate] = fline.split('|')

          if (finame == fil3 and fiSize == filsize and fidate == filtime and fiMD5 != hashy):
                    print(finame + ': match')
          else:
                    print(finame + ': is OK')
```

And here is the error message I get when I try to run the program:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\a\b\c\checkfile.py", line 21, in <module>
    [finame, fiMD5, fiSize, fidate] = fline.split('|')
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

ere is an example of what the other program outputs, of which the MD5 checker reads from and refers to:

C:\pytesty\pyt01\ex2.txt|7a9d20dd22c96bea3ea1fa0d01085755|69|Mon May  8 19:01:00 2017|

Comment: There are 4 pipes, so your line split by `|` will have 5 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple test:

```
>>> 'C:\pytesty\pyt01\ex2.txt|7a9d20dd22c96bea3ea1fa0d01085755|69|Mon May  8 19:01:00 2017|'.split('|')
['C:\\pytesty\\pyt01\\ex2.txt', '7a9d20dd22c96bea3ea1fa0d01085755', '69', 'Mon May  8 19:01:00 2017', '']
>>> len(_)
5 # you actually get more values
```

But `[a, b, c, d] = "string".split("|")` means "take the values returned by `split` and stuff each one into a variable". So, there *must* be exactly *four* values in the list returned by `split`, but there actually are five, hence the error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what this means for my program. I'm not sure what I would have to change, please could you elaborate?

Comment: @AdamJones you just get rid of the last variable returned by `split` and that's it: `a, b, c, d = "stuff".split("|")[:-1]`.

Comment: I have solve this issue, thanks. However I am now facing another issue, when I run the program it says the following in the console: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  a41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\egwe.bmp: is OK. However, I know that the file is not 'ok' because the file size and all other properties except the MD5 sum remain the same, since all I changed was the MD5 found in the report file.

Comment: Apologies for not quoteing the output, I wanted to edit but exceeded the max number of edits.

Comment: @AdamJones, if you have other issues with your code, please consider asking another question. Note that `OK` will be printed if the `if` condition isn't satisfied. The latter is quite complicated, so it's enough for only one condition to be `False` for the `if` to go to `else`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `fline` (read from the file `MD5report.dat`) are more than 3 `|` separators, i. e. more than 4 parts to split them with your command

```
 [finame, fiMD5, fiSize, fidate] = fline.split('|')
```

If it is not an error and you have *intentionally* more than 4 parts (in lines of the file `MD5report.dat`), put underscores (`_`) as placeholders for the skipped parts, e. g.

```
[finame, fiMD5, fiSize, fidate, _, _] = fline.split('|')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the string into 5 parts as mentioned in the comments on your original post. However, you are only providing four variables to store the five strings. You need to add an extra variable to catch the `fifth` string from 
`fline.split('|')`

example:

```
[finame, fiMD5, fiSize, fidate, value] = fline.split('|')
```